# Why is this thought experiment on the speed of light wrong?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I'm trying to better understand Einstein's special relativity but I reach a point where I see an inconsistency. I thought I'd share it to see if someone could enlighten me on what I am missing.

A rehash of special relativity: All observers measure the same speed of light regardless of their velocity relative to the light. This is the reason time dilates for objects moving at different velocities. Since the measurement of the speed of light is the same in all reference frames, it must mean the reference frames are experiencing time at different paces.

Consider the following thought experiment: A magic Chia Pet is launched from Earth and accelerates to a speed of 0.95c relative to Earth. The magic Chia Pet travels far far away but its velocity relative to Earth remains constant. The magic part of the Chia Pet is that it collects raw space matter (astroids, space dust, parts of planets and stars) and can mold the raw matter into a planet with water and an intelligent civilization.

So now what was originally a Chia Pet launched from Earth and accelerated to 0.95c has transformed into an intelligent civilization still moving at 0.95c away from Earth. Since the planet is moving at constant velocity, the inhabitants can't tell the difference between being on this planet and Earth.

The inhabitants of the new planet decide to launch another Chia Pet at 0.95c relative to the new planet. After the launch, this second Chia Pet accelerates to 0.95c relative to the new planet and 0.95c + 0.95c = 1.9c relative to Earth. How is that possible if nothing moves faster than c?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one issue with this question is that it uses a lot of words to ask about a core topic covered in a first-year relativity textbook. I kind of empathize with both the question asker and the down voters, since this is a completely reasonable question you should ask the first term you learn relativity (and the search term for the answer isn't necessarily obvious), but there are also a lot of "why haven't I disproved relativity" questions that boil down to, "if you read a first-year level textbook on relativity, this question is covered in great detail."

Comment: Again not a downvoter, but I would join in Andrews comment, that you used too many words for a very simple thing. The creation of whole new planets and civilizations doesn't add anything of value, it only pollutes the core question. You could just start with two planets moving relative to each other at 0.95c, or start just by accelerating some other planet without all this raw space matter collecting and intelligent life creation stuff. This might have a higher literary value, but I think it just retracts from the actual physics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assuming that speeds add straightforwardly, which is only approximately true when they are small compared with c. Adding two speeds, v, that are close to c does not result in a total speed  of 2v, but a total speed that is not much more than v. In the example you cited, where v is 0.95c, the overall speed that results is about 0.9987c, so the speed of light is not exceeded. Google the relativistic velocity addition formula for more details.

Comment: If the two speeds are $\frac{a-1}{a+1}$ and $\frac{b-1}{b+1}$, in units where $c=1$, then the combined speed is $\frac{ab-1}{ab+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the inhabitants of Earth 1.0 use a laser to broadcast "News from Home" to Earth 2.0. That news obviously must reach Earth 2.0 because the news is moving along at the speed of light, and they are moving more slowly. But suppose *they* measure the speed of that laser beam? What value do they get?

Well, it's *light* isn't it? and you said, "All observers measure the same speed of light regardless of their velocity relative to the light." The information carried by the laser beam may be somewhat Doppler shifted, but the *beam* passes them at the speed of light.

Now, Earth 3.0 is following that same beam, moving along at the speed of Earth 2.0 plus 0.95c. The "News from Home" obviously must reach Earth 3.0 because it's moving past Earth 2.0 at the speed of light, and Earth 3.0 is moving more slowly...

---

If what you said really is true, If "all observers measure the same speed of light regardless of their velocity relative to the light," then you should be getting the feeling that something weird is happening. Earth 3.0 cannot outrun the light beam, and neither can Earth 4.0, or 5.0, 6.0, etc.

Physicists were somewhat bothered by this idea back at the dawn of the 20th century after James Clerk Maxwell predicted that all observers measure the same speed of light regardless of their velocity relative to the light. They came up with a number of crazy ideas of how to make sense of it all, and eventually, Albert Einstein wrapped those ideas up into a nice, self-consistent "theory of relativity."

Nobody has found fault with it yet.